# Assign local state value to redux state value?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to assign local state value to the redux state value, and when I write console.log(action) to know weather actions are getting my values or not then it shows that it getting my values but redux state is not assigning those values! Please give solution...

App.js:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {addName} from './action';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      first:''
    };
  }
  inputData = event => {
    this.setState({
      first:event.target.value
    });

  }
  submitData = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.addName({
      firstName:this.state.first
    });
    console.log(this.props.firstName)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          <input type="text" name="first" onChange={this.inputData}/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    firstName : state.firstName
  };
};
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return{
    addName: bindActionCreators(addName,dispatch)
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Main index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {rootReducer} from './reducers/name';
import {createStore} from "redux";
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
let store = createStore(rootReducer)
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

reducer name.js:

```
const init = {firstName: ''};

export let rootReducer = (state=init,action) => {

  switch(action.type)
  {
    case 'ADD_ENTRY':
    {
      return{
        firstName:action.firstName
      };
    }
    default:
    {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

My action component index.js

```
export const addName = action => {
  return{
    type:'ADD_ENTRY',
    ...action
  };
};
```

please check that when I try to assign using action.firstName at that time I think the assigning is not done, so please check my reducer correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you aren't updating your reducers state, you are simply returning the value passed to the reducer from the action. Instead, you need to first update `state.firstName`, and then return the **entire** reducer state:

**EDIT**:

[**Working example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/21r4ro5yqj)

```
const init = {firstName: ''};

export let rootReducer = (state=init,action) => {

  switch(action.type)
  {
    case 'ADD_ENTRY':
    {
      return {...state, firstName: action.firstName }
    }
    default:
    {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `mapStateToProps` looks wrong too. Can you post the value of `state` that you get in `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: I'm posting sandbox link please verify it.....https://codesandbox.io/s/jvo39j18l9

Comment: The sandbox doesn't work, you are missing the actions.

Comment: @NehaDobia Fixed it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/21r4ro5yqj. In your reducer, you cannot mutate state. You need to return a new copy of state.

Comment: Can you see that when I doing conole.log(this.props.firstName) it doesn't show in console that value?

Comment: @NehaDobia Fixed here: https://codesandbox.io/s/21r4ro5yqj. You were checking the props before they were being set. You should use `componentDidUpdate` to check for props **after** they have been updated.